# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeVietnameseTones') in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular.

I have a function which is running normally in ReactJS with JS.

```
const _onSearch = value => {
  onTextChange(value);

  let filtered = drivers.filter(function (car) {
    return removeVietnameseTones(car.DriverName)
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(removeVietnameseTones(value).toLowerCase());
  });

  setFiltered(filtered);
};
```

But I have try it in Angular with TS

```
onSearch(value: string): void {
  this.searchValue = value;
  console.log(this.removeVietnameseTones(value)); // this line run

  this.outputData = this.outputData.filter(function (item) {
    console.log(this.removeVietnameseTones(value)); // this line error
    console.log(this.removeVietnameseTones(item.unitName)); // this line error

    return this.removeVietnameseTones(item.unitName) // this line error
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(this.removeVietnameseTones(value).toLowerCase());
  });
}
```

it's undefined.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeVietnameseTones')

So where did I go wrong?

My [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cdzmxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Use an arrow function instead `=>` for your filter. It fixes it on stackblitz.

Comment: I really dont think about it. Because all of them run normally in ReactJS -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **Arrow Function** instead of **Function**

`filter(function (item) {})` => `filter((item) => {})`